# SQLite convert String of values delimited by commas into a List

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a field called 'languageids' of which can contain multiple ids e.g. 0,1,2,3 or a single value e.g. 2. I need to be able to select movies that have a particular ID. I am limited to using functions that are available within SQLite. I am not allowed to restructure the existing database or modify the entries.

**Structure**

```
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | title | genre | languageids |
+----+-------+-------+-------------+
```

**Example Data**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | title     | genre     | languageids  |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | "Movie 1" | "Action"  | "1,2,5,8,10" |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | "Movie 2" | "Romance" | "2,4"        |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 3  | "Movie 3" | "Comedy"  | "3,8,21"     |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

If I was to fetch all movies with the language id 2 I should get back the movie that have the ID 1 and 2 but not 3. Is there any where to split this string up into a list of which I can do `"languageId IN languageids"`? If not, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Normalization is the key.

Comment: This is an existing project that I am not allowed to modify the database of so i need a query :)

Comment: can you add seprator in the start and end of languageids like **',2,4,'**, If so, you can use like statement

Comment: I see what you mean but I can't modify the existing data or else that would have been a perfect solution

Comment: It seems obvious that the person who made this model has absolutely no idea how relational databases work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
select * from tablename where ',' || languageids || ',' like '%,2,%'
```

it will gave you all records containing language id 2

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you! Helped solved something I've been stuck on for a while

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (id,title,genre,languageids)
as (
select 1,      'Movie 1',        'Action',      '1,2,5,8,10' union all
select 2,      'Movie 2',        'Romance',     '2,4'        union all
select 3,      'Movie 3',        'Comedy',      '3,8,21'
)
select * from t where (',' + languageids + ',') like '%,2,%'
```

Comment: `"I should get back the movie that have the ID 1 and 2 but not 3"` and let's assume that string ids are not sorted. Anyway your code will return also `12,`

Comment: @lad2025 - You are correct, prefixed comma at the beginning will solve the issue. Of course, normalization is the right way...